# AWS Central Mounting for Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, nfs, amazon-efs

We need an option to mount `/var/www/html/` folder on multiple servers to EFS or some other services for setting up autoscaling environment.

Firstly we have used EFS and faced an issue such that, at high throughput, and if the file size is not increasing, then it will burst.

So could you please suggest an alternative for high throughput and the file size not increasing rapidly.

Comment: Is this static files ? If yes why don’t you use S3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using EFS with auto-scaling and I have faced the same issue as yours then I have done the below solution.

1. I have mounted a drive at any mount point at "/home/code" which is using XFS filesystem and deploy the code in this particular directory. I am taking up snapshot after every deployment using script ([Link](https://github.com/ethicalmohit/scripts/blob/master/snapshot_status.sh)).

2. I am using the ec2 bootstrap script to create a volume from this snapshot with high IOPS which automatically attaches to the new instance which are coming in.

Alternatively, you can tar your code at every time you deploy and copy the code to the new servers which are coming in through bootstrap script itself.